# Find the sum of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k (1-x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was working on this and thought that it didn't matter what my function was. However I noticed in order to solve it like I usually do. It has to look like 
$$\sum a_k x^k$$
However mine does not look like that. It does not have an $x^k$.  $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^k (1-x)$$

I am positive the sum exists but don't know how I should find it.

Comment: Try splitting it up into two sums, using $x^k(1-x)=x^k-x^{k+1}$.

Comment: I believe I have to show that they are both convergent in order to do that? So if I show they are both convergent when $|x| < 1$ then is it okay to use it?

Comment: Yes, this is valid if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}x^k(1-x)=x^2(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i =x^2,$$
if $|x|<1$.

---

If $|y|<1$ then $$\frac{1}{1-y} = 1+y+y^2+\cdots = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} y^i.$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $|x|<1$; then 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}x^k(1-x)
&=(1-x)\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}x^k\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^k-(1-x^2)\\
&=\frac{1-x}{1-x}-1+x^2\\
&=x^2
\end{align*}